# boost async_wait return handler never gets called

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am working with the `boost::asio tcp`, version 1.57, creating a custom server/client, roughly following this example: [Async_Tcp_Client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp) , but I'm running the io_service run() in it's own thread per server/client. Also, there can be multiple server/clients per application.

Following the example I put my `await_output` function to sleep when I DON'T want to send a Message, and waking it up when I do want to send one (via `async_write`). After a varying amount of send-operations (sometimes less then 10, sometimes several thousand) I run into strange behaviour of my `await_output` Deadline (a boost deadline timer).
At some point, the `async_wait` against the timer just "disappears" and doesn't return when I cancel the deadline to send a message.

The `transmit` function, that is called by the Application owning the Client/Server (only by the application though, I guess it is not very threadsafe);
The `await_output` function that is waiting on the `mOutputQueueDeadline`;
And the `handle_write` function:

```
void SocketTcp::transmit(std::string pMsg) {
    if (mStopped)
    { return; }

    mOutputQueue.push(pMsg); // a global queue

    // Signal that the output queue contains messages. Modifying the expiry
    // will wake the output actor, if it is waiting on the timer.
    size_t quits = mOutputQueueDeadline.expires_at(boost::posix_time::neg_infin);
//this returns '0' when the error occurs
}


void SocketTcp::await_output(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (mStopped)
    { return; }

    if (mOutputQueue.empty())
    {
        size_t quits = mOutputQueueDeadline.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

        mOutputQueueDeadline.async_wait(boost::bind(&SocketTcp::await_output, this, _1)); 
        //this async_wait starts a wait on the deadline, that sometimes never returns!
    }
    else
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(mSocket, 
                            boost::asio::buffer(mOutputQueue.front()), 
                            boost::bind(&SocketTcp::handle_write, this, _1));
    }
}


void SocketTcp::handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (mStopped)
    { return; }

    if(!ec)
    {
        mOutputQueue.pop(); //remove sent element from queue
        boost::system::error_code errcode;
        await_output(errcode); //start the waiting actor for outgoing messages
    }
    else
    {
        mConnected = false; //update the connection status
        this->stop();
    }
}
```

I tried implementing a workaround, restarting the `await_output` in `transmit()` when `expire_at` returns 0, but that leads to TWO actors beeing awakened the next time I send a message, and then running into a crash (`String iterator not dereferencable` - the design doesn't allow for parallel send OP, much less trying to send the same message...)

I tried debugging with the `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING` option, and found the error here:

```
@asio|1468415460.456019|0|deadline_timer@000000000050AB88.cancel //transmit cancels the timer
@asio|1468415460.456019|>474|ec=system:995 //await_output is called
@asio|1468415460.456019|474*479|socket@000000000050A9D8.async_send //starts the async send
@asio|1468415460.457019|<474|
@asio|1468415460.457019|>479|ec=system:0,bytes_transferred=102 //async send returns to it's handler
@asio|1468415460.457019|479|deadline_timer@000000000050AB88.cancel
    //this cancel op is the only difference to the 'normal' order,
    //not sure where it originates though!!
@asio|1468415460.457019|479*480|deadline_timer@000000000050AB88.async_wait //the handler starts the new async wait
    //handler 480 never gets called when the deadline is canceled the next time
@asio|1468415460.457019|<479|
```

I'm pretty new to c++ as well as the stackoverflow (even though it has already safed me multiple times!) so please tell me if I can improve my question somehow!

Comment: How many threads does your ioservice have? Do you have a worker attached to it in order to prevent it from stopping?

Comment: frankly I would drop this approach immediately. follow the guidelines in the documentation. create a wait object, call io_service::run in as many threads as you need and then call io_service::stop() followed by joining the threads. You don't need a thread-per-client in an async model. 1 thread per core is more like it.

Comment: I completely agree with @RichardHodges .You can also take a look at the [boost asio HTTP Server 2, 3, and 4 examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html) for better ways to do it.